# How to se defaultValue for AtlasKit editor/editor-core?

Tags: reactjs, atlaskit

I'm trying to get a simple controlled component going that outputs a string of html and takes in a string of html.

Unfortunately atlaskit team turned off issues in the repo. I see this link on google, but can't actually see it on bitbucket (sigh): https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlaskit-mk-2/issues/89/way-to-get-html-as-it-is-in-atlaskit

Has anyone else given this a try? None of the docs seem to be updated. The defaultValue field, when given a string, spits out "not valid json".

https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/editor/editor-core

```
  import { EditorContext, WithEditorActions } from '@atlaskit/editor-core';
  import { CollapsibleEditor } from 'previous-example';

  <EditorContext>
    <div>
      <CollapsibleEditor />
      <WithEditorActions
        render={actions => (
          <ButtonGroup>
            <Button onClick={() => actions.clear()}>Clear Editor</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => actions.focus()}>Focus Editor</Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  </EditorContext>;
```

The above example won't work and neither do any of the "transformers" that supposedly get the value ready for the editor.

https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/editor/editor-json-transformer

From the little I've gathered, it seems like it takes a

It sucks because the editor is beautiful and all the other facets seems to be working well, I just can't get a damn default value in there which makes it hard to use as an input for editing values.

I understand why atlaskit team turned off issues (programmers these days are ungrateful, to say the least). Hopefully somebody can help me here though!

Further Reading:
- I think it uses prosemirror: https://discuss.prosemirror.net/t/how-to-create-a-mention-plugin-similar-to-atlaskit-supporting-popup/1439

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple things going on here. First, you're import, `import { CollapsibleEditor } from 'previous-example';`, is wrong.  Within an example on [their website](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/editor/editor-jira-transformer) (check the code for that example) it's actually called the `CollapsedEditor` and wraps the editor component. So you'll need to fix your imports before it will work.

As for using an HTML string and exporting it, I struggled with this as well so I dug into the source code. Here's a basic example that should get your started:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Editor, WithEditorActions } from '@atlaskit/editor-core'
import { JIRATransformer } from '@atlaskit/editor-jira-transformer'

export const AtlaskitSimple = () => {
  return (
    <Editor
      contentTransformerProvider={schema => new JIRATransformer(schema)}
      defaultValue={'<p>Hey there!</p>'}
      primaryToolbarComponents={
        <WithEditorActions
          render={actions => (
            <button
              onClick={async () => console.log(await actions.getValue())} //'<p>Hey there!</p>'
            >
              Save
            </button>
          )}
        />
      }
    />
  )
}
```

You need both `defaultValue` and the `[JIRATransformer][1]` to make it work. The reason is because the editor uses it's own format under the hood (couldn't find any docs so you'll have to dig into the source to see what I mean). Lastly, you need to wrap your button in `[WithEditorActions][2]` to gain access to the editor methods that allow you to pull out the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default value for the editor. But the process isn't straightforward. Here's how will do it:

a> The editor does accept data when you provide it in a JSON format, so lets start by creating the JSON that the editor accepts

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { EditorView } from 'prosemirror-view';
import {
  Editor,
  CollapsedEditor,
  WithEditorActions,
  EditorContext,
  EmojiResource,
} from '@atlaskit/editor-core';

const MainEditor = () => {
  const [firstTimeRenderingdoc, setFirstTimeRenderingdoc] = useState(true);

  const onEditorChange = (editorView: EditorView) => {
    setFirstTimeRenderingdoc(false);

    const output = editorView.state.doc;
    // Now you can save this output doc anywhere and use it inside actions.replaceDocument() function below
  };
  return (
    <EditorContext>
      <div>
        <Editor onChange={onEditorChange} />
        <WithEditorActions
          render={(actions) => (
            <div>
              {actions.replaceDocument(JSON.parse(`load that JSON here`))}
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </EditorContext>
  );
};
```

Inside onEditorChange, we're fetching the JSON that the editor can read, you can save the output wherever you want and then render the data inside `actions.replaceDocument()` (You may need to parse it as well)

PS :- that `firstTimeRenderingdoc` helps us solve a bug of editor rendering in a loop.